# Shapeless everywhere and asynchronous computations

Tags: shapeless

The Shapeless feature overview contains an example of using `everywhere` function to [recursively transform a tree, by applying a given function](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#generic-representation-of-sealed-families-of-case-classes):

```
object inc extends ->((i: Int) => i + 1)

everywhere(inc)(tree)
```

My question: if we had an `asyncInc` function which returns a `scala.concurrent.Future[Int]`, how could one implement a `asyncEverywhere` function, that would return a `Future` of the modified `Tree`?

The usage would look as follows:

```
object asyncInc extends ->((i: Int) => Future { i + 1 } )

val treeFuture: Future[Tree[Int]] = asyncEverywhere(asyncInc)(tree)
```

Answer (score 2):

If I were to write the `asyncEverywhere` method, I would call `everywhere` twice, with different functions passed to it.

The first one would be a side-effecting identity function.
As a side effect it would start an appropriate `Future` and added it to a mutable list.
When the first pass of traversal completes, I get a list of `Future`s.

Now I can call `Future.sequence` to transform it into a `Future` of lists. I call `map` on this `Future` to transform the list in a following 
way:
- I call `everywhere` on the `Tree`, this time with another function. That second function just pulls its subsequent results out of the lists, starting from left (keep in mind, this would be a mutable list). Since the size of the list matches the number of elements processed.

Here's how that could look like:

```scala
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.language.postfixOps

def asyncEverywhere[T](asyncF: T => Future[T], tree: Tree[T])
  (implicit ec: ExecutionContext) = {

  val queue = scala.collection.mutable.Queue[Future[T]]()

  object enqueueFutures extends ->({ (i: T) =>
    queue.enqueue(asyncF(i))
    i
  })

  everywhere(enqueueFutures)(tree)

  Future.sequence(queue) map { q =>
    object dispenseResults extends (T -> T)(_ => q.dequeue())
    everywhere(dispenseResults)(tree)
  }
}

println(Await.result(
  asyncEverywhere(
    (i: Int) => Future { i + 1 },
    tree),
  1 minute))
```